# Why is the DOM itself referred to as an API?

Tags: dom

With sentences such as these

'...This tree structure and the relationships between the elements are described using a standard API called the Document Object Model or DOM, which is a W3C standard...'

'...Of course, you can do all of this using the standard DOM API, which is now implemented in all major modern browsers. The DOM API, however, is very verbose, and sometimes it takes quite a bit of code to accomplish what you want to do. JQuery solves this problem by providing a layer of API functions over the standard DOM that simplify a lot of common operations...'

I am led to believe that the DOM is a bit more than what I just typed into my text editor.
Please expound upon what is implied by the language being used in referring to the DOM as an API.

Answer (score 5):

What you type into your text editor is *marked up content*. The markup uses a *markup language* like Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) or Extensible Markup Language (XML).

When this is served to a browser, it is *parsed*. This parsing converts the marked up content to an internal, tree structured, object graph, called a *Document*. The browser provides a collection of methods and properties through which this object graph can be read or manipulated. Although, each browser's internal object graph may be quite different from other browsers, the methods and properties are *standardized*. That is, each browser provides the same methods and properties regardless of its internal object graph.

These methods and properties collectively form an *Application Programming Interface* (API). It's possible for alternative collections of methods and properties to be defined to read and manipulate the object graph but the particular collection that JavaScript uses in browsers is called the *Document Object Model* (DOM).

Because the DOM API is the *only* collection of methods and properties natively available to JavaScript in browsers for manipulating the object graph, the distinction between this collection and the internal object graph that it accesses is normally not relevant, so the term "DOM" is often used as if it were the object graph itself.